# How to recursively render JSON tree as HTML using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

Suppose I have the following JSON structure in my javascript as a variable named `myTree`:

```
[
    {"name": "A", "children": [
            {"name": "C", "children": []},
            {"name": "D", "children": []},
        ]
    },
    {"name": "B", "children": []}
]
```

I would like to use AngularJS to render it as the following HTML. How can I do it?
FYI, the tree can have arbitrary depth. I have shown only a very simple example here.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        A
        <ul>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>D</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>B</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make recursive templates:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="item_template">
 {{child.name}}
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="child in child.children" ng-include="'item_template'">
    </li>
  </ul>
</script>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="child in myTree" ng-include="'item_template'">
  </li>
</ul>
```

So, you will render 'infinite' levels of recursion, no only the first level.

Comment: How is this recursive? I don't see any function calling itself here. For it to be recursive, there would have to be a calll from within the `<li ng-repeat="child in children"></li>` to `item_template`.

Comment: @Saqib Ali: It was missing a ng-include attribute on the <li> inside the template.